# Are ASP.NET MVC route tests considered Unit Tests or Integration Tests?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, unit-testing, testing, routes, integration-testing

So i'm going to add some tests to my project to test my ASP.NET MVC routes. Are they a unit test or an integration test?

I feel like they are a unit test, where integration tests are against db's, 3rd party services (eg. twitter, file upload, etc) .. something I would normally mock out in a unit test.

The reason I'm asking is that I was looking at [Ayende's Raccon Blog](https://github.com/ayende/RaccoonBlog) and noticed they have their route tests listed as Integration Tests.

Answer (score 0):

I would consider them to be unit tests. Your just testing that an endpoint reaches a particular controller action. I think that's a pretty isolated set of functionality.